# How to insert data once in a mysql database, and then keep updating that? Java / Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, boolean

I want to do the following: I want to check if my database table already exists. If it doesn't, it should make it (createEntry). Once it has made that one record, I want to keep updating that same record (updateEntry) with new information (so basically overwrite the first record with the new information).

The problem I have now with my boolean is that it creates the database (which is good), but when I read another QR code and want to update the info in my record, it just writes the information in a second record. Basically it keeps doing createEntry instead of updateEntry.

What might be wrong with the boolean? I can't seem to find it.

```
private void insertQR(String doctorID, String doctorFullName, String patientID, String apiKey) {
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    databaseHelper.open();  
     boolean dbExist = checkDB();

    if (dbExist == true)
    {
        databaseHelper.createEntry(doctorID, doctorFullName, patientID, apiKey);
    }

    databaseHelper.updateEntry(0,doctorID, doctorFullName, patientID, apiKey); 
    databaseHelper.close();
}

private boolean checkDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/rem.med.artesis/databases/qrreader.db", null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            checkDB.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // database doesn't exist yet.
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }


}
```

Comment: You are checking the wrong thing for what you want. You need to be checking if the entry exists. If it exists, update it. If not, then create it.

Comment: I think you should have some kind of conditions on which you want to update like on certain kind of ID's if it gets matched then update the table, or you can use some kind of UPSERT logic that will update and insert both just like using MERGE.

Answer (score 1):

Your `checkDB()` returns true if the database exists. Therefore, Your `if` statement will always create that entry. You need to check for the existence of that table as well. Use the [SQLiteDatabase.query()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in order to determine if your table exists.

Comment: and how exactly do I do that?

Comment: Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)